# Generating a random array with additional constraints

Tags: python, numpy, random, memory-management

I'm trying to generate a numpy array of random values, satisfying some additional constraints, and for a given fixed length N. Is it better to:

Make a list (sampling once at a time), then convert it to a numpy array

```
while len(list)<N:
    num=np.random.rand(1)
    if num <.5:
        list.append(np.random.rand(1))
x=np.array(list)
```

Use vectorized code, and *append* to the array:

```
x=np.array([])
while x.shape[0]<N:
    x=np.append(x,np.random.rand(int(N/2))
    x=x[x<.5][:N]
```

Overshoot the array length, then try until the masked version is long enough

```
x=np.array([])
while x.shape[0]<N:
    x=np.random.rand(4*N)
    x=x[x<.5][:N]
```

Comment: is num < .5 just a dummy or an actual constraint?

Comment: Dummy one. As much as 1/2 and 4 in second and third example.